# D3 - adding an interpolated point to a trend line

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am writing a React application and want to draw a line chart with an interpolated point, similar to the blue cross in the below:
[image: line chart with interpolated point]

I have been able to achieve mostly what I want using [Nivo](http://nivo.rocks/line) but this only drawers points based explicitly on data. What I want to do is illustrate an interpolated point along the trend line based on the x-axis. Is there a way to do this, either using Nivo or D3 directly?

The code I'm using for my line graph currently:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Line } from 'nivo';

class LineGraph extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="line-graph">
                <Line
                    width={600}
                    height={350}
                    margin={{
                        top: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        bottom: 60,
                        left: 60,
                    }}
                    data={[{
                        id: 'Distribution',
                        data: [
                            {x: '1', y: 0.09 },
                            {x: '2', y: 0.16 },
                            {x: '3', y: 0.5 },
                            {x: '4', y: 0.06 },
                            {x: '5', y: 0.19 },
                    ]
                    }]}
                    colors="#ff6384"
                    enableArea
                    yScale={{ type: 'linear', stacked: false }}
                    curve="monotoneX"
                    dotSize={8}
                    dotBorderColor="#ff6384"
                    dotBorderWidth={2}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: you are using some kind of curve so you have to find the Y belonging to an X with binary search and `path.getTotalLength()` and `path.getPointAtLength()`